# How to save a PictureBox image in varying formats?

Tags: c#, picturebox, file-format, savefiledialog

I have a picture box that will contain an image generated during run-time. I need to save this image using a SaveFileDialog, for which I have found the fallowing code:

```
 private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

This works however, I need to allow the user to specify in the FileDalog what format they want it to be saved as.
The allowed formats for the user:

Bitmap (*.bmp),

GIF (*.gif),

JPEG (*.jpg),

and  PNG (*.png).
Any examples or recommendations on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somthing like this could be a good place to start

```
        var fd = new SaveFileDialog();
        fd.Filter = "Bmp(*.BMP;)|*.BMP;| Jpg(*Jpg)|*.jpg";
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            switch (Path.GetExtension(fd.FileName))
            {
                case ".BMP":
                    pictureBox.Image.Save(fd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    break;
                case ".Jpg":
                    pictureBox.Image.Save(fd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```